# Jdbc template nested entities rowmapper

Tags: spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I try to find a quick and good solution to retrieve database query results, using spring boot java backend application & spring jdbc template. Could you please share your experience, what is the best way to map entity with a list of nested entities?

Lets say, I have a simple example:

```
create table if not exists student(
  id bigint primary key,
  name varchar(25) not null
)

create table if not exists discipline(
  id bigint primary key,
  name varchar(25) not null,
  student_id bigint not null,
  foreign key (student_id) references student(id)
)
```

I perform sql query to retrieve all students and disciplines:

```
select 
  s.name as student, 
  d.name as discipline 
from student s 
left join discipline d on d.student_id = s.id
```

Lets say I receive this kind of result set:

```
   |  name:  |  discipline:
---+---------+--------------
1. |  peter  |  math
2. |  peter  |  astronomy
3. |  peter  |  physics
4. |  george |  math
5. |  katy   |  dancing
```

I'd like to use a RowMapper that supports population of nested collection for `discipline` list of values. But there is no any available implementation from jdbc template.

Otherwise, I think that common approach is to perform two queries: first for students and second for disciplines and merge results by `student_id` but this looks like rudimentary approach.

Could anyone advice a good alternative, please?